# New to Ubuntu and looking to find a stand alone desktop CRM...

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, downloads

I have just joined the Ubuntu community (I was advised to stick with 12.04 lts).  I own and operate my own business from home and I am looking for some type of CRM download that is not web based.  I am also not a code master....I just need to be able to keep up with tasks, assign tasks, chat, to do list, customer contact info and scheduling ect.  I have been searching for the past cpl hours and have yet to find something close :(  I appreciate the help!!
~Michelline~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the most user-friendly one is Dolibarr (http://www.dolibarr.org/), you can give that a try. Other alternatives include ERP5 (http://www.erp5.org/) and JFire (Which I don't have any personal experience with).